# Using regex to get values in multiline text

Tags: javascript, regex, localization

I have the following scenario:

I would like to extract all strings between "" **after .html(** of the JS code below using Regex.

This is what I have done so far:

```
(\.html\()?"(.+)"\s*\+*
\.html\("(.+)"(\s*\+\s*\n\s*"(.+)")*
```

But does not work for all lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

JavaScript Code

```
     sym.getSymbol("popup").$("main").html("Delamination at Sharp Points and Corners");
     sym.getSymbol("popup").$("sub").html("<span style='font-family: abel_probold'>Defect:</span> Bond separates easily at the tip of a sharp edge or corner.<br><br>" +
         "<span style='font-family: abel_probold'>Common cause:</span> Very little adhesive area to hold the application in place<br><br>" +
         "<span style='font-family: abel_probold'>Corrective action:</span> When possible, eliminate sharp points. Validate bond performance with wash testing.</div>");
```

Comment: Parsing javascript and HTML with a regex is generally not a very good idea ?

Comment: Do you want to extract just `.html("..."` strings ?

Comment: @sln yes, including strings separated by +

Comment: Why do you need to extract the strings, and what do you plan to do with them once you've extracted them?

Comment: Its not good enough to try to parse strings of a language with `".*?"`. It just doesn't work that way. Beside the fact that you don't know what double quote relates to an open or close, languages contain comment constructs that hide any number of possible quotes that throw off real quoted literals. In the end, you have to parse, that means _match_ every single character in the source to get what you want.

Comment: @torazaburo I am extracting these strings for translation. Then I will return them with the same method.

Comment: There are many viable approaches for handling translation of webapps, but extracting strings from JS with regexp and replacing them is not one of them. In general, a jQuery-based application which makes extensive use of `.html` and DOM built up via strings is going to be very hard to localize. You're better off taking this opportunity to switch to a modern framework which uses templates, many of which provide better ways to handle the localization process.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you for your comments. I am trying to develop something in c# that would help extracting the strings from this kind of file. I got an approach from floribon and Alexey Shein answers. Perhaps didn't ask correctly that is why didn't get a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match everything that's between a quote and that is not a quote:

```
string.match(/\"([^\"]*)\"/g)
```

Comment: It works but I need the strings after ".html(". How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can do `string.split('html(')[1]`to only keep what's after it, so you don't end up with a regexp too ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
string.match(/\.html\((.+?)\)/gs)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xW5yR3/1